# Not able to read data from elasticsearch using alpakka

Tags: elasticsearch, akka, akka-http, alpakka

I was trying to read document(json data stored in ES) from elasticsearch using alpakka.
I got this [alpakka-Elasticsearch](https://doc.akka.io/docs/alpakka/current/elasticsearch.html).
Here it says that you can stream messages from or to Elasticsearch using the
`ElasticsearchSource, ElasticsearchFlow or the ElasticsearchSink`.
I tried to impliment ElasticsearchSource method. So my code looks like this

```
  val url = "http://localhost:9200"
  val connectionSettings = ElasticsearchConnectionSettings(url)
  val sourceSettings = ElasticsearchSourceSettings(connectionSettings)
  val elasticsearchParamsV7 = ElasticsearchParams.V7("category_index")
        val copy = ElasticsearchSource
          .typed[CategoryData](
            elasticsearchParamsV7,
            query = query,
            sourceSettings
          ).map { message: ReadResult[CategoryData] =>
          println("Inside message==================>  "+message)
          WriteMessage.createIndexMessage(message.id, message.source)
        } .runWith(
          ElasticsearchSink.create[CategoryData](
            elasticsearchParamsV7,ElasticsearchWriteSettings(connectionSettings)
          )
        )
  println("Final data==============>.  "+copy)
```

At the end, copy value returning `Future[Done]`.
But I was not able to read data from ES.
Is there Something I missing?
And also is there any other way using akka http client api to do the same?
What is preferred way to use ES in akka?

Comment: Could it be that your query doesn't return any result?

Comment: val query = Json.obj(
          "query" -> Json.obj(
            "bool" -> Json.obj(
              "must" -> Seq(
                Json.obj(
                  "match" -> Json.obj(
                "isDeleted"-> false)
                )
                )
            ))
        ).toString()

Comment: The above comment is my query which I want to execute on category_index. But still not able to read data.

Answer (score 0):

To read data from Elasticsearch, sth like this should be enough:

```
  val matchAllQuery = """{"match_all": {}}"""
  val result = ElasticsearchSource
    .typed[CategoryData](
      elasticsearchParamsV7,
      query = matchAllQuery,
      sourceSettings
    ).map { message: ReadResult[CategoryData] =>
    println("Read message==================>  "+message)
  }.runWith(Sink.seq)

  result.onComplete(res => res.foreach(col => println(s"Read: ${col.size} records")))
```

If the type `CategoryData` does not match correctly to what is stored in the index, the query may not return results.

If in doubt, it's possible to read raw JSON:

```
  val elasticsearchSourceRaw = ElasticsearchSource
    .create(
      elasticsearchParamsV7,
      query = matchAllQuery,
      settings = sourceSettings
    )
```